# Form in embedded controller not submitted

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have form embedded in a modal, I used an embedded controller to handle this.

This is my code : 
The controller :

```
 public function affectProduitsAction(Pack $pack)
{
    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();

    $form = $this->createForm(PackAffectProduitType::class, $pack);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { /*success*/

    }
    return $this->render('pack/affect_produits.html.twig', [
        'packForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

The layout : render the embedded controller  :

```
 <div class="button-add">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-upper" data-target="#modalAffectProduit" data-toggle="modal">
                    <i class="os-icon os-icon-ui-22"></i>
                    <span>Affecter des produits</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            {{ render(controller(
                'AppBundle:Pack:affectProduits',
                {'pack': pack }
            )) }}
```

The modal : rendered from the embedded controller:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="modalAffectProduit" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                Affecter des produits
            </h5>
            <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"> &times;</span></button>
        </div>
        {{ form_start(packForm, {'action':
            {# the problem is here I don't know how call the embedded controller #}
        }) }}
            <div class="modal-body">
                  ......
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"> Annuler</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Affecter</button>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(packForm) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is : when I click the submit button nothing happened . I want to call the embedded controller from the form action but I don't know how since it does not have routing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add routing to your controller, only then form will know the path where to send the request. And add Request $request parameter to action

```
public function affectProduitsAction(Request $request, Pack $pack)
{
.
.
.
```

and delete

```
$request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
```

Comment: It will not work because if add routing to the controller, it will go to embedded template (the modal above).

Comment: after form submitting?

Comment: Yes, the form is in a modal so the controller should not have routing.

Comment: so if form is submitted and valid you do what you want to do with it and redirect to the route which render correct template, but if form is submitted and not valid you can add bagFlash message with error and  redirect to the route which render correct template,

Comment: So if form is not submitted, then it will render only the modal with form.

Comment: `$request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();` worked for me. allowed me to check the form was submitted in 

`$form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())// code here
                }`

Comment: @DevLine if it works, then i guess u have route that points to that controller?